# .htaccess rewrite rule with multiple {QUERY_STRING}s

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a website project where we basically move from TYPO3 to a WordPress & Magento-solution.

Before launching the new site, I would like to add rewrite rules to point the old (TYPO3, non-SEF) URLs to the corresponding new ones. I have an Excel-list with around 1000 URLs that I somehow would like to add to htaccess and create 301's.
If you have a better approach for this, I'd be thankful.

What I am struggling with is:

The "old" URL structure looks something like `?id=123\&user_e15proddb1_pi1[domain]=42`

the correcponding new URL would be
`/de/alle-produkte/neuheiten.html`

RewriteEngine is on, RewriteBase is /.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123\&user_e15proddb1_pi1[domain]=42$
RewriteRule . /de/alle-produkte/neuheiten.html [R=301,L]
```

With additionally escaping the `_`and the `[]` with no avail.
I tried to seperate the `{QUERY_STRING}`s into two by

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user_e15proddb1_pi1[domain]=42$
```

followed by TheRule. Also no avail.

Rewriting itself works, because I tried

```
RewriteRule .id=123\&user_e15proddb1_pi1\[domain\]=42$ /de/alle-produkte/neuheiten.html [R=301,L]
```

But that only works without the question mark in the beginning.

Could you give me a hint on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule by escaping `[` and `]`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123&user_e15proddb1_pi1\[domain\]=42$
RewriteRule ^ /de/alle-produkte/neuheiten.html? [R=302,L]
```

Also note `?` at the end of target URI to strip off any existing query string to prevent a redirect loop.

Comment: I think the dot (`.`) as selector for the URL to rewrite was somehow wrong.
You solution works fine, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes dot in pattern will not match landing page as that would by matched using `^$`. It is safer to use `^` to match all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to and made this one work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123\&user\_e15proddb1\_pi1\[domain\]=42$
RewriteRule (.*) /de/alle-produkte/neuheiten.html? [R=301,L]
```

Proably something with escaping those characters was going wrong when I tried over and over again.